# Convert a pandas dataframe column values into column names

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe in the below format:

```
       no     point1    point2  point3    
  1    101    roof      garage  basement  
  2    102    basement  garage  painting
```

I am trying to go over the above pandas dataframe and come up with a below dataframe. For example, for no "101", if "roof" is present, I would need to populate it with "1" in df_final, if not it has to be populated with "0".

df_final = ['no','roof','garage','basement']

df_final:

```
     no   roof  garage  basement    painting
1    101    1       1       1           0
2    102    0       1       1           1
```

Not sure whether there is a functionality to convert it into the above format. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Where does `painting` come from in your expected output?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny: Thanks, I have made an edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `get_dummies()` ([Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html)):

```
pd.get_dummies(df)
```

Alternatively if you want it all "nicely combined":

```
pd.get_dummies(df,prefix='', prefix_sep='').groupby(level=0, axis=1).max().set_index("no")
```

Comment: I tried it, it doesn't work as I have a fixed set of columns in df_final that has to be populated based on the initial dataframe.

Comment: @user3447653 - `pd.get_dummies(df, prefix='', prefix_sep='')` will remove the prefix. This answer should solve your question or you are missing requirements in your question.

Comment: I think I made an edit that gets it a bit more how you'd like it